# Can Javascript Determine PNG or JPG?

Tags: javascript, image

I don't know if this is even possible, but is there a way to decipher between a JPG and a PNG in Javascript?  I am assuming not, but if I could get help with a different way do do what I am trying to do.

I need to set an image if it is a JPG or a PNG.  Right now I am adding an extension to my built string because I am only getting a int back from my code.

I was wondering if I could Just tell it to add an extension using an if/else statement.
Something like use '.jpg' or '.png' that way is one is not there there the other could be used.

```
if (JPG) {
        img.attr('src', samplePath + 'pages/' + page + '.jpg');
    }
    else {
        img.attr('src', samplePath + 'pages/' + page + '.png');
    }
```

Any help or direction is much appreciated

Comment: In your sample code, where does `JPG` get its value?

Comment: Like.. what are you trying to decipher?

Comment: @Carlos It's possible, but you have to get your data somehow.  It isn't clear at all from your question how you're doing that.  Much more info needed.

Comment: If you have an image given to you, shouldn't you have the filename? If that's the case, just do a regex for the extension, something like /\.jpg$/i

Comment: Are you asking how to check whether your server has a JPG or PNG file with that name?

Answer (score 0):

Scan the MIME type by inspecting headers in an XMLHttpRequest.

MIME types:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image

XHR/XMLHttpRequest:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

First, use jQuery.

Then, let's say you had your markup like this:

```
<img src="images/1x1.png" test-src="images/3" test-ext="jpg|png|gif" />
```

Then, you could add an onerror event handler to the image like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('img[test-src][test-ext]').each(function () {
        // closures
        var $img = $(this);
        var sSrc = $img.attr('test-src');
        var sTestSrc = sSrc;
        var aExtensions = $img.attr('test-ext').split('|');
        var iTest = 0;
        var fAttemptLoad = function () {
            if (iTest < aExtensions.length) {
                sTestSrc = sSrc + '.' + aExtensions[iTest];
                $img.attr('src', sTestSrc);
            }
        };

        // event method closures
        var fFailTest = function () {
            // increment test extension
            iTest++;
            // if there are still tests to run?
            if (iTest < aExtensions.length) {
                fAttemptLoad();
            }
        };

        // event handler
        $img.error(fFailTest);

        // initial state, start test.
        fAttemptLoad();
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9d276/6/